# if with multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Don't know how to clearly explain it, so I'll just give an example:
xml file:

```
<root>
  <one>
    <a a="x"/>
    <a a="y"/>
  </one>
  <two>
    <a a="x"/>
    <a a="y"/>
  </two>
</root>
```

and here's an xsl:

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:variable name="self" select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="one/a/@a = $self/two/*/a/@a">
          <xsl:text>it works</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just want the if to work...

//edit

An explanation:

```
<requirements>
    <bar/><restaurant/>
</requirements>
<offer>
    <bar/></beach><restaurant/><nightclub/>
<offer>
```

so i want the 'if' to check if all (in this case) elements of 'requirements' are satisfied by the elements of 'offer'

Comment: What do you want the `if` condition to test, exactly?

Comment: Is the if statement supposed to mean "Find any a under "one" where its @a matches any of the a's under "two" with the same @a parameter?"  It's unclear what your if statement is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Greg, I think he is trying to check if there is a match in `two` for the item in `one/a`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest XPath 2.0 expression that evaluates to the desired boolean value :)

Comment: Edited my answer and added an XPath 1.0 one-liner solution to your first problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElementByName" match="requirements/*" use="name()"/>
    <xsl:template match="offer[count(*[key('kElementByName',name())])
                               = count(../requirements/*)]">
        <xsl:text>Success!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input (well formed):

```
<root>
    <requirements>
        <bar/>
        <restaurant/>
    </requirements>
    <offer>
        <bar/>
        <beach/>
        <restaurant/>
        <nightclub/>
    </offer>
</root>
```

Output:

```
Success!
```

**Note**: The use of `xsl:key` because functions implicit node set casting to scalar only takes the first node.

XPath 2.0 expression:

```
every $name in /root/requirements/*/name() 
satisfies $name = /root/offer/*/name()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
not($requirements[not(name()=$offer/name())])
```

**where**:

`$requirements` is `/*/requirements/*`

**and**

`$offer` is `/*/offer/*`

**and these are evaluated against the XML document below** (essentially the provided non-wellformed XML made well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <requirements>
        <bar/>
        <restaurant/>
    </requirements>
    <offer>
        <baz/>
        <beach/>
        <restaurant/>
        <nightclub/>
    </offer>
</t>
```

**The same technique for your initial problem:**

```
not(/*/one/a[not(@a = /*/two/a/@a)])
```

**Note that the above is a one-lener XPath 1.0 solution**.  **: )**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="self" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="aKey" select="one/a/@a"/>

    <xsl:if test="$self/two/*/a[@a=$aKey]">
      <xsl:text>it works</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

XSLT 1.0 Solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="validTest">
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/requirements/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'+')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="offer">
    <xsl:if test="count(/*/requirements/*) = count(*[
                                    contains($validTest,
                                        concat(name(),'+')
                                        )
                                    ])">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('#', @id, ' is a valid offer!&#xa;')"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the XML sample:

```
<root>
  <requirements>
    <bar/><restaurant/>
  </requirements>
  <offer id="1">
    <bar/><beach/><restaurant/><nightclub/>
  </offer>
  <offer id="2">
    <bar/><beach/><nightclub/>
  </offer>
  <offer id="2">
    <beach/><nightclub/><restaurant/>
  </offer>
  <offer id="4">
    <bar/><beach/><restaurant/><nightclub/>
  </offer>
</root>
```

produces this result:

```
#1 is a valid offer!
#4 is a valid offer!
```

Comment: it doesn't work properly - if you change 'a' attribute in one from 'x' to something else it still prints 'it works' but it shouldn't

Comment: so you need attribute values to be compared, taking into account attributes position? e.g. if first _one/a/@a_ matched first _two/a/@a_?

Comment: position is irrelevant, look at another example at the end my question, I've cleared that out

Comment: @Flack: I would consider to add a starting separator to the container and to the item concatenation test, otherwise names like `man` and `superman` could end in wrong results.

Comment: @Alejandro, it still would be slower. Yours is better.

Comment: @Flack and @Alejandro: My solution might be interesting to you -- just a  shortish  XPath 2.0 one-liner...

Comment: @Flack and @Alejandro: Also added an XPath 1.0 one-liner. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for

> test="every $x in $self/one/xxx
>   satisfies some $y in $self/two/yyy
>   satisfies $x = $y"